# configure size temdb

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I have a disk space of 743 GB which contains the tempdb database

there was a request to set the max size tempdb to 669GB keeping 10% percent as free disk space

I have 8 tempb file + log file

how can I distribute these values ​​between the mdf and ldf files

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In theory the tempdb tlog shouldn't grow too much, but in the real world I would take your available space and divide it by 9.

Answer (score 0):

Your TempDB log file should be moved to where all of your user database log files are stored. The SQL limitations around TempdDB only relate to the data files. Take the space you have for your data files and divide by 8.